# Is this possible to pass locators from properties file to @FindBy annotation in POM?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have stored all my ***xpaths*** and ***locators*** on properties file. I'm trying to use them in `Page Object Repository` and finding elements by `@FindBy` annotaion. I want to use all stored locators here.

While using properties file value in `@FindBy` I'm getting compilation error saying `the value for annotation must be a constant expression`.

Can someone help me understanding? Please suggest me some workaround if possible.

Comment: You can store your locators in a java class with static final string variables for each locator. Then you will be able to use a static reference in the FindBy.

Answer (score 1):

The values of the `@FindBy` annotation must be evaluated in *compile time*, i.e. the value is known before the program start running. Values from properties file are evaluated in *run time*, so they can't be used in `page factory`.

Options you have are

- Put the locator as fixed string in the `@FindBy` code instead of reading it from properties file.
- Don't use `page factory` and initialize the elements when you create the page object instance.
- Don't use `page factory` and initialize the elements only when you are using them.

Comment: Thanks `@Guy` and `@grasshopper`.